# Calling ActionClass in tiles.xml using Struts 2.0

Tags: struts2, tiles

I reviewed the example of tiles with struts2.0 and found that in tiles.xml jsp pages are called like:

```
<definition name="welcome" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title"  value="Welcome"/>
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/welcome.jsp"/>
```

BUT my question is if I want to call the action class instead of .jsp pages than how to call it like

```
<definition name="friends" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title"  value="Friends"/>
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/checkActionLink.action"/>
```

when I am trying to write to execute the above code than its showing the error that checkActionLink.action is not found....thanks in advance for the help.....

Following is the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Struts2Example15</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much research I found out that adding the following tag:
`<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in the web.xml the issue gets resolved.

Now the question arises why?
As per my understanding when we add any action as the value of **value** attribute of the `<put-attribute/>` tag the request is forwarded to the mentioned action so the action is executed successfully.

Previously `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` tag was missing so this issue was caused.

I would really appreciate if any correction is there in my understanding.

Thanks. Happy Coding :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You'll need to create a jsp and use the struts2 action tag in it.  That can call an action and render part of it's page. If you make a jsp only using the action tag, you'll probably get the effect you want.  Have never tried this, but you can probably insert the name of the action and namespace from tiles into the action tag before the jsp is invoked.

I would be very interested to hear how this works out for you.

Comment: I am really surprised to see that the code works by adding some changes to my web.xml file  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>. Seriously I dont know how it works but its working...hope you can find out the reason behind it...thanks.

Comment: Can you post your whole web.xml, into your question?

Comment: I have posted the whole xml file. Please have a look into it. Thanks.